# Adding a variable to an array using a Post Form

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post

I want to add my $_POST variable to my array every time I submit a name. With this code it empties the array every time I use the Form. How should I do this if I want to add to the array everytime I submit a name?

```
<?php
    $array = array();

    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        $new_name = $_POST['name'];

        array_push($array, $new_name);
    }

    print_r($array);
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See you need something that will remember what $array was, even after a refresh. So either you would need to save it in a database / cookie.

Here is an example using a session ($_SESSION).

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['names'])){
    $_SESSION['names'] = array();
}
if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    $_SESSION['names'][] = $_POST['name'];
}
foreach($_SESSION['names'] as $name){
    echo $name . '<br>';
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

If you don't understand anything, please do ask.

Comment: So how would I destroy this array if someone closes the site? I'm making a system in which the site chooses 3 people at random. The persons are provided by the person.

Comment: The session is unique to each browser, it will not be visible to other users.

Comment: Do you need it to be?

Comment: OK! What would be the best way to only display the names and not the array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "Steve" [1]=> string(4) "Bill" [2]=> string(5) "Mark" }

Comment: No it needs to be personal.

Comment: A foreach loop, I will update the answer for you. - Updated

Comment: Thanks! It works! What is the difference between array_push and what you are using right now?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!